# get email to insert order

Tags: php, email, for-loop

I want how to get email message in input order from add more field datas. Please anyone guide me, I'm not experience in `php`.

**input screen is:**

[image]

**expected output screen:**

[image]

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{


$your_email ='xxxxx@gmail.com';

$frommail ='yyy@gmail.com';
    $randnum = rand(1111111111,9999999999);
        $place = $_POST[ 'place' ];
        $companyname = $_POST[ 'companyname' ];
        $business = $_POST[ 'business' ];
        $products = $_POST[ 'products' ];
        $suppliers = $_POST[ 'suppliers' ];
        $buyers = $_POST[ 'buyers' ];
        $experience = $_POST[ 'experience' ];
        $annualsales = $_POST[ 'annualsales' ];
        $employees = $_POST[ 'employees' ];
        $operation = $_POST[ 'operation' ];
        $website = $_POST[ 'website' ];
        $fund = $_POST[ 'fund' ];
        $authorised = $_POST[ 'authorised' ];
        $standard = $_POST[ 'standard' ];
        $special = $_POST[ 'special' ];
        $currency = $_POST[ 'currency' ];
        $parvalue = $_POST[ 'parvalue' ];
        $noofshares = $_POST[ 'noofshares' ];


$capital = $_POST[ 'capital' ];
        $surname = $_POST[ 'surname' ];
        $givenname = $_POST[ 'givenname' ];
        $address = $_POST[ 'address' ];
        $occupation = $_POST[ 'occupation' ];
        $shares = $_POST[ 'shares' ];
        $percent = $_POST[ 'percent' ];
        $national = $_POST[ 'national' ];
        $passport = $_POST[ 'passport' ];
        $dirsurname = $_POST[ 'dirsurname' ];
        $dirgivenname = $_POST[ 'dirgivenname' ];
        $dircompanyname = $_POST[ 'dircompanyname' ];
        $diraddress = $_POST[ 'diraddress' ];
        $dirbusiness = $_POST[ 'dirbusiness' ];
        $dirnational = $_POST[ 'dirnational' ];
        $dirpassport = $_POST[ 'dirpassport' ];
        $comname = $_POST[ 'comname' ];
        $comaddress = $_POST[ 'comaddress' ];
        $combusiness = $_POST[ 'combusiness' ];
        $comnationality = $_POST[ 'comnationality' ];
        $compass = $_POST[ 'compass' ];
        $agename = $_POST[ 'agename' ];
        $ageaddress = $_POST[ 'ageaddress' ];
        $ageoffice = $_POST[ 'ageoffice' ];
        $bankdetails = $_POST[ 'bankdetails' ];
        $savings = $_POST[ 'savings' ];
        $usdollarssavings = $_POST[ 'usdollarssavings' ];
        $hongkongcurrent = $_POST[ 'hongkongcurrent' ];
        $tradeac = $_POST[ 'tradeac' ];
        $others = $_POST[ 'others' ];
        $online = $_POST[ 'online' ];
        $atm = $_POST[ 'atm' ];
        $phonebanking = $_POST[ 'phonebanking' ];
        $banksign = $_POST[ 'banksign' ];
        $eitherone = $_POST[ 'eitherone' ];
        $twobank = $_POST[ 'twobank' ];
        $arrangement = $_POST[ 'arrangement' ];
        $postalcode = $_POST[ 'postalcode' ];
        $correspondence = $_POST[ 'correspondence' ];
        $financial = $_POST[ 'financial' ];
        $name1 = $_POST[ 'name1' ];
        $email1 = $_POST[ 'email1' ];
        $mobile1 = $_POST[ 'mobile1' ];
        $tel1 = $_POST[ 'tel1' ];
        $skype = $_POST[ 'skype' ];
        $address12 = $_POST[ 'address12' ];
        $knowour = $_POST[ 'knowour' ];
        $true = $_POST[ 'true' ];
        $clean = $_POST[ 'clean' ];
        $criminal = $_POST[ 'criminal' ];
        $letterscode = $_POST[ 'letterscode' ];
      $num2=$_POST['ex'];
    foreach($_POST["surname1"] as $key1 => $surnames){
        @$surname2 .= $surnames."<tr><td colspan='3'>";
    }

    foreach($_POST["givenname1"] as $key1 => $givennames){
        @$givenname2 .= $givennames."<tr><td colspan='3'>";
    }

    foreach($_POST["address1"] as $key1 => $addresss){
        @$address2 .= $addresss."<tr><td colspan='3'>";
    }
    foreach($_POST["occupation1"] as $key1 => $occupations){
        @$occupation2 .= $occupations."<tr><td colspan='3'>";
    }


    foreach($_POST["shares1"] as $key1 => $sharess){
        @$shares2 .= $sharess."<tr><td colspan='3'>";
    }
    foreach($_POST["percent1"] as $key1 => $percents){
        @$percent2 .= $percents."<tr><td colspan='3'>";
    }

    foreach($_POST["national1"] as $key1 => $nations){
        @$nation2 .= $nations."<tr><td colspan='3'>";
    }

    foreach($_POST["passport1"] as $key1 => $passports){
        @$passport2 .= $passports."<tr><td colspan='3'>";
    }


    if(empty($errors))
    {
        //send the email
        $to = $your_email;
        $subject="New form submission";
        $from = $frommail;
        $ip = isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : '';
        $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
<div><h2>New Registration Document</h2></div>
<div>
<h4>Yeah! $name</h4>
<p>Registration Details<br /></p>

 <b>Application No : $randnum</b>
<br />
<br />
<table border="1"  cellpadding="15"  style="width:100%; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black;">
<tr>
<td style='font-weight:800;'>1. State:</td>
<td colspan="2">$place</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:800;  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;'>2. Company:</td>
<td colspan="2">$companyname</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3" align="center" style='font-weight:800; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;'>3. Main line of Business</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>(a) Nature of Business/Industry:</td>
<td colspan="2">$business</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>(b) Nature of Products/Services Offered</td>
<td colspan="2">$products</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>(c) Location of suppliers:</td>
<td colspan="2">$suppliers</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>(d) Location of Buyers:</td>
<td colspan="2">$buyers</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>(e) Years of Experience:</td>
<td colspan="2">$experience</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>(f) Expected Annual Sales: </td>
<td colspan="2">$annualsales</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>(g) Number of Employees:</td>
<td colspan="2">$employees</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>(h) Location of Business operation: </td>
<td colspan="2">$operation</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>(i) Website:</td>
<td colspan="2">$website</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>(j) Source of Initial Fund:</td>
<td colspan="2">$fund</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:800; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;' colspan="3" align="center">4. Captial</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Authorised:</td>
<td colspan="2">$authorised</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Standard</td>
<td colspan="2">$standard</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Special</td>
<td colspan="2">$special</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:500;' colspan="3" align="center">Par Value Per Share</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>A. Currency</td>
<td colspan="2">$currency</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>B. Parvalue</td>
<td colspan="2">$parvalue</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>C. No of Shares</td>
<td colspan="2">$noofshares</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>D. Capital</td>
<td colspan="2">$capital</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:800; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;' colspan="3" align="center">5. Shareholders</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >Sur Name : $surname</td>
<td colspan="2">Givenname : $givenname</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Address : $address</td>
<td colspan="2">Occupation : $occupation</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Shares : $shares</td>
<td colspan="2">Percent : $percent</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>National : $national</td>
<td colspan="2">Passport : $passport</td>
</tr>

<tr><td style='font-weight:800;' colspan="3">Surname</td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">$surname2</td></tr>
<tr><td style='font-weight:800;' colspan="3">Givenname</td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">$givenname2</td>
</tr> 
<tr><td style='font-weight:800;' colspan="3">Address</td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">$address2</td>
</tr> 
 <tr><td style='font-weight:800;' colspan="3">Occupation</td></tr>
 <tr>
<td colspan="3">$occupation2</td>
</tr>
<tr><td style='font-weight:800;' colspan="3">Share</td></tr>
 <tr>
<td colspan="3">$shares2</td>
</tr>
<tr><td style='font-weight:800;' colspan="3">Percent</td></tr>
 <tr>
<td colspan="3">$percent2</td>
</tr>
<tr><td style='font-weight:800;' colspan="3">National</td></tr>
 <tr>
<td colspan="3">$nation2</td>
</tr>
<tr><td style='font-weight:800;' colspan="3">Passport</td></tr>
 <tr>
<td colspan="3">$passport2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='font-weight:800; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;' colspan="3" align="center">6. Directors</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Surname : $dirsurname</td>
<td colspan="2">GIvenname : $dirgivenname</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Company Name : $dircompanyname</td>
<td colspan="2">Address : $diraddress</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Business : $dirbusiness</td>
<td colspan="2">National : $dirnational</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">Passport No : $dirpassport</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:800; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;' colspan="3" align="center">7. Company Secretary</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Company Name : $comname</td>
<td colspan="2">Address : $comaddress</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Business : $combusiness</td>
<td colspan="2">National : $comnationality</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">Passport No : $compass</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:800; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;' colspan="3" align="center">8. Registered Agent</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Agent Name : $agename</td>
<td colspan="2">Address : $ageaddress</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:800; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;' colspan="3" align="center">9. The Registered Office will be situated at</td></tr>
<td colspan="3">Office : $ageoffice</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:800; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;' colspan="3" align="center">10. Bank Details</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Name of the Bank:</td> 
<td colspan="2">$bankdetails</td>
</tr>
<tr><td style='font-weight:500; color: #c29d0b; ' colspan="3">Type of accounts required : </td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Multi-currency Savings A/C : $savings</td>
<td colspan="2">U.S. Dollars Savings A/C : $usdollarssavings</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Hong Kong Dollars Current A/C : $hongkongcurrent</td>
<td colspan="2">Trade A/C (For L/C, D/P, D/A) : $tradeac</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">Others : $others</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:500; color: #c29d0b;' colspan="3" align="center">Services Required</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Online Banking Service : $online</td>
<td colspan="2">ATM Card  : $atm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">Phonebanking Service : $phonebanking</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Name of Bank Signatory:</td>
<td colspan="3">$banksign</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:400; color: #c29d0b; ' colspan="3" align="center">Signing Arrangement</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Either one bank signatory can operate bank account solely : $eitherone</td>
<td colspan="2">Any two of bank signatories can operate bank account jointly : $twobank</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:400;'  align="center">Other Arrangement</td>
<td colspan="2">$arrangement</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:400;'  align="center">Bank Address & Postal code</td>
<td colspan="3">$postalcode</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:800;' colspan="3" align="center">11. Correspondence Address</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Address</td>
<td colspan="5">$correspondence</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:800;' colspan="3" align="center">12. Financial Year End Date</td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" >$financial </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:800;' colspan="3" align="center">13. Authorization to proceed with the above instruction and SX Global is requested to send the Company’s documentation and invoice to</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name : $name1</td>
<td colspan="2">Email : $email1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mobile : $mobile1</td>
<td colspan="2">Tel : $tel1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Skype : $skype</td>
<td colspan="2">Address : $address12</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style='font-weight:800;' colspan="3" align="center">14. How do you know our company</td></tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="3" >$knowour</td>
</tr>

<tr style='font-weight:800;' colspan="5" align="center">
<td colspan="3" >15. Declaration</td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5">I confirm that the above information is true and correct. : $true</td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5">I confirm that the fund of the entity is clean and legitimate.   : $clean</td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5">I confirm that the new Company will not be used for criminal activities. : $criminal</td>
</tr>

</table>
<br />

<p>IP-Address : $ip</p>
    </div>
</div>

EOD;

$to = $your_email;
$subject="New form submission";
$from = $frommail;
$headers = "From: $from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $frommail \r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

        if(mail($to, $subject, $body,$headers)){

        echo "<div class='container'><div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable'>
                                            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' >&times;</button> Thank you for your registering! We will get back to you very soon.
                                        </div></div>";
        }
      else {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'>
                                            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' >&times;</button> sorry.
                                        </div> ";
        }
    }
}
```

**Html code (add more field code)**

```
    <script>
    var counter = 1;
    var limit = 5;

    function addInput(divName) {
        if (counter == limit) {
            alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " Shareholders");
        } else {
            var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
            newdiv.innerHTML = "Shareholders - " + (counter + 1) + " <br> <div class='form-group form-md-line-input'> <div class='col-lg-6'> Sur Name :           <input type='text' class='form-control col-md-12 ' name=surname1[]> </div> <div class='col-lg-6'>Given Name :<input type='text' class='form-control col-md-12' name='givenname1[]'></div> </div> <br /><br /> <br /> <div class='form-group form-md-line-input '><div class='col-lg-6'>Address :           <input type='text' class='form-control col-md-12 ' name='address1[]'> </div> <div class='col-lg-6'> Business Occupation :<input type='text' class='form-control col-md-12' name='occupation1[]' > </div> </div><br /><br /><br /><div class='form-group form-md-line-input '><div class='col-lg-6'> No. of Shares :<input type='text' class='form-control col-md-12' name='shares1[]'> </div><div class='col-lg-6'>Percent of Shareholding :             <input type='text' class='form-control col-md-12' name='percent1[]'></div></div><br /><br /> <br /><div class='form-group form-md-line-input '>        <div class='col-lg-6'> Nationality : <input type='text' class='form-control col-md-12' name='national1[]'></div><div class='col-lg-6'> Passport/Identity Card No. / Company No : <input type='text' class='form-control col-md-12' name='passport1[]'></div></div><br /> <br /><br />";
            document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
            counter++;
        }
    }

</script>
```

I don't know which method to use. Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

The table isn't formatted correctly. You need to do something like

```
<tr>
  <td style='width:50%;'><br>Sur Name</b>: $surname</td>
  <td><b>GivenName</b>...</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This is putting each item on it's own line (<tr><td>..</td></tr>). If you want multiple columns you need multiple <td>'s within a <tr>.

Comment: >first thank u for replying @jeff , ok thats correct but i my prob is not that field `<tr><td style='font-weight:800;' colspan="3">Surname</td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">$surname2</td></tr>
<tr><td style='font-weight:800;' colspan="3">Givenname</td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">$givenname2</td>
</tr> 
<tr><td style='font-weight:800;' colspan="3">Address</td></tr>
<tr>` in this field (add more dynamic fields)

Comment: iam sorry i dnt konw english fluently